# The radius of a circle passing through a circle and the centre point of another smaller circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: the figure describing the problem]

My idea was determining the equation of the smallest circle of which it might determine the equation of the moddle circle but I was not pretty sure

Answer (score 1):

$$AC=2\sqrt{11^2-(11-8)^2}=2\sqrt{112}.$$
$$AB^2=\sqrt{112+4^2}=\sqrt{128}.$$
Thus, $$R=\frac{AB\cdot BC\cdot AC}{4S_{\Delta ABC}}=\frac{128\cdot2\sqrt{112}}{4\cdot\frac{4\cdot2\sqrt{112}}{2}}=16.$$

Comment: Please explain why you come up with $sqrt(11^2-(11-8)^2)$

Comment: If $PK$ is an altitude of $\Delta PAC$  then $PK=11-2\cdot4=3.$ Thus, $AK=\sqrt{PC^2-PK^2}=\sqrt{11^2-3^2}=\sqrt{112}$.